# How to limit decimal values to 2 digits before applying agg function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.5

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032025/how-to-sum-the-values-of-one-column-of-a-dataframe-in-spark-scala) solution from one of the stack overflow post, my only requirement here is how can I limit the values that I want to sum to 2 digit after the decimal before applying the `df.agg(sum())` function?

For examples: I have values like below and the sum function sums it,

```
2.346
1.549
```

However I want the values to be rounded to 2 digit after the decimal like

```
2.35
1.55
```

before summing it. How can I do it? I was not able to find any sub function like `sum().round` of function `sum`.

Note: I am using Spark 1.5.1 version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [bround](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#bround(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)):

```
val df = Seq(2.346, 1.549).toDF("A")
df.select(bround(df("A"), 2)).show
+------------+
|bround(A, 2)|
+------------+
|        2.35|
|        1.55|
+------------+


df.agg(sum(bround(df("A"), 2)).as("appSum")).show
+------------------+
|            appSum|
+------------------+
|3.9000000000000004|
+------------------+
                                          ^
df.agg(sum(df("A")).as("exactSum")).show
+--------+
|exactSum|
+--------+
|   3.895|
+--------+
```

Comment: Hi @Psidom it looks like bround is available from spark 2.0 version is there anything similar available in 1.5.1 version?

Comment: It seems that [round](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#round(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)) is the a more universal version and available since 1.5.0. You can give it a try. Not sure why there are two functions doing the same thing though.

Comment: @Psidom: Actually they're not the same. `bround` uses *HALF_EVEN rounding mode* while `round` uses *HALF_UP rounding mode*

Answer (score 5):

The above solution does work for spark 2.0 version however for folks like me who are still using 1.5.*+ versions below is something that will work.(I used round function as suggested by @Psidom):

```
val df = Seq(2.346, 1.549).toDF("A")
df.select(bround(df("A"), 2)).show
+------------+
|bround(A, 2)|
+------------+
|        2.35|
|        1.55|
+------------+

val total=df.agg(sum(round(df.col(colName),2)).cast("double")).first.getDouble(0)
total: Double = 3.90
```