# How Can I Get Accumulated Value Based on Time, Using pyspark SQL?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like that:

[image]

In this table,`artist_id` stands for a particular singer, `Ds` is a date(from 2015 Mar 1st to the end of Apr) and `like` is how many people liked this singer's songs in this particular day.
I want to get the accumulated value of `like`, for example, in the day 20150303, the value will be the sum of original value of 20150301 and 20150302 and 20150303.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregate functions provided by spark and get the output.

Your question says, based on time, but as per schema, its actually a column of date, hence you aggregate on `Ds` and get sum of `like` similar to

```
df.groupBy("Ds").sum("like")
```

Update:
To get the sum of all days previous to provided date, `Reduce` can be used after applying `filter` for the provided date to fetch results of this and previous date and then summing up all using `reduce` or aggregate function `sum`

more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032902/2319984)

Comment: groupBy'Ds' and then sum can only get a single day's data sum, but I want to sum data of all days before a day and this day.